# No Form data from postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Have A really simple form that isnt sending any data back to my controller.

Controller :

```
public class SurveysController : Controller
{
    private IAdminBusinessLogic _logic;
    //
    // GET: /Admin/Surveys/
    public SurveysController(IAdminBusinessLogic logic)
    {
        _logic = logic;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Tables = _logic.ListTables();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AddTable()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("AddTable")]
    public  ActionResult AddTablePost()
    {
        return Content(Request.Form["submit"]);
    }
}
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Table";
    Layout = "";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Delete" />

}
```

Fiddler

```
POST http://localhost:56366/Admin/Surveys/AddTable HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:56366
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20120204 Firefox/10.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:56366/Admin/Surveys/AddTable
Cookie: __utma=111872281.928520945.1315324301.1325785813.1325895119.6; __utmz=111872281.1315324301.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddler request shows that there are no post-data. The Content-Length is zero. That is because your input is missing a name.